# build-id data offset in the ELF file

Tags: linux, elf

I need to modify the `build-id` of the ELF notes section. I found out that it is possible [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63382584/modify-build-id-in-the-notes-section-of-the-elf-file). Also found out that I can do it [by modifying this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29052125/reading-the-contents-of-an-elf-sectionprogrammatically). What I can't figure out is data location. Here is what I'm talking about.

```
$ eu-readelf -S myelffile

Section Headers:
[Nr] Name                 Type         Addr             Off      Size     ES Flags Lk Inf Al
...
[ 2] .note.ABI-tag        NOTE         000000000000028c 0000028c 00000020  0 A      0   0  4
[ 3] .note.gnu.build-id   NOTE         00000000000002ac 000002ac 00000024  0 A      0   0  4
...


$ eu-readelf -n myelffile

Note section [ 2] '.note.ABI-tag' of 32 bytes at offset 0x28c:
  Owner          Data size  Type
  GNU                   16  GNU_ABI_TAG
    OS: Linux, ABI: 3.14.0

Note section [ 3] '.note.gnu.build-id' of 36 bytes at offset 0x2ac:
  Owner          Data size  Type
  GNU                   20  GNU_BUILD_ID
    Build ID: d75a086c288c582036b0562908304bc3a8033235
```

`.note.gnu.build-id` section is 36 bytes. The build id is 20 bytes. What are the other 16 bytes?

I played with the code a bit and read 36 bytes of `myelffile` at offset `0x2ac`. Got the following `040000001400000003000000474e5500d75a086c288c582036b0562908304bc3a8033235`.

Then I decided to use  [`Elf64_Shdr` definition](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/source/include/uapi/linux/elf.h#L317), so I read data at address `0x2ac + sizeof(Elf64_Shdr.sh_name) + sizeof(Elf64_Shdr.sh_type) + sizeof(Elf64_Shdr.sh_flags)` and I got my build id, `d75a086c288c582036b0562908304bc3a8033235`. It does makes sense why I got it, `sizeof(Elf64_Shdr.sh_name) + sizeof(Elf64_Shdr.sh_type) + sizeof(Elf64_Shdr.sh_flags) = 16 bytes`, but according to [`Elf64_Shdr` definition](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/source/include/uapi/linux/elf.h#L317) I should be pointing to `Elf64_Addr sh_addr`, i.e. section virtual address.

So what is not clear to me is what are the other 16 bytes of the section? What do they represent? I can't reconcile the [`Elf64_Shdr` definition](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/source/include/uapi/linux/elf.h#L317) and the results I'm getting from my experiments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> .note.gnu.build-id section is 36 bytes. The build id is 20 bytes. What are the other 16 bytes?

Each `.note.*` section starts with `Elf64_Nhdr` (12 bytes), followed by (4-byte aligned) note name of variable size (`GNU\0` here), followed by (4-byte aligned) actual note data. [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/819-0690/chapter6-18048.html).

Looking at `/bin/date` on my system:

```
 eu-readelf -Wn /bin/date

Note section [ 2] '.note.ABI-tag' of 32 bytes at offset 0x2c4:
  Owner          Data size  Type
  GNU                   16  GNU_ABI_TAG
    OS: Linux, ABI: 3.2.0

Note section [ 3] '.note.gnu.build-id' of 36 bytes at offset 0x2e4:
  Owner          Data size  Type
  GNU                   20  GNU_BUILD_ID
    Build ID: 979ae4616ae71af565b123da2f994f4261748cc9
```

What are the bytes at offset `0x2e4`?

```
 dd bs=1 skip=$((0x2e4)) count=36 < /bin/date | xxd

00000000: 0400 0000 1400 0000 0300 0000 474e 5500  ............GNU.
00000010: 979a e461 6ae7 1af5 65b1 23da 2f99 4f42  ...aj...e.#./.OB
00000020: 6174 8cc9                                at..
```

So we have: `.n_namesz == 4`, `.n_descsz == 20`, `.n_type == 3 == NT_GNU_BUILD_ID`, followed by 4-byte `GNU\0` note name, followed by 20 bytes of actual build-id bytes `0x97`, `0x9a`, etc.